# Omni-directional navigation

Tags: navigation, base-local-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
i am currently working with an omni-directional platform and try to get the navigation stack running. This already working but only in a differential drive manner. Is there any stack/repository which already implemented a omni-directional path planner/execution? I looked into the tum package, since rosie seems to move in some videos omni-directional.

Regards,
Frederik

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12363/omni-directional-navigation/) by [Frederik](https://answers.ros.org/users/1545/frederik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2011-12-15

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ben_S](https://answers.ros.org/users/1072/ben_s/) on 2011-12-15**:
Just to make sure: Is your local_base_planner (http://www.ros.org/wiki/base_local_planner ) configured with holonomic_robot set to true? Acording to the docs, thats what makes the planner issue strafing commands to the base. Otherwise it uses differential mode. Best regards, Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As @Ben_s mentioned, the navigation stack supports holonomic (omni-direction) path planning. The pr2 has this ability. If you set the `holonomic_robot` parameter to `true`, move_base will generate plans that contain both x and y motion, and it will output a `cmd_vel` message with an x, y, and theta component, rather than just an x and theta. It's up to you to interpret this message appropriately for the drive train of your robot.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2011-12-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3